# Breeze.js using noTracking not unwrapping entities

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am trying to execute a query locally.  I am chaining on .noTracking() to the query but it is not unwrapping the entities.

```
var result = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from('ResourceName')
    .where('id', '==', 1)
    .expand('OtherEntities')
    .noTracking()
    .using(manager)
    .executeLocally();
```

I have tried the same query using fromEntities, executeQueryLocally, and a bunch of other variations but I can't get back an unwrapped entity.

I could use Select but I would rather not have to as I am also using expand.

**Does EntityQuery only work with noTracking() when hitting the server?**

Using Breeze.js 1.4.7 and Knockout 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, the EntityQuery noTracking method is only applicable when querying a server.  We will update the documentation so that this is clearer.

Comment: Gentle reminder November 2016. It would be nice if this was in the documentation http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_noTracking

Comment: We are currently rewritting breeze.js into typescript (fully backward compatible) so I'll get this included in the new docs. thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a limitation. To execute a query locally means to seek the entities in cache. "No tracking" means "I don't want entities in cache". It's a contradiction to query for entities in a place they aren't supposed to be.

Comment: True however the unwrapped pojos with expanded properties would be really powerful.

Comment: I would like to understand the scenarios in which this is "really powerful". Maybe that could motivate a feature. Also have you looked at the [documentation on entity serialization](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-serialization)? There might be some useful clues there.

Comment: Yes I have, many times :).  Imagine a deep nested tree of entities with navigation properties.  A league has teams, a team has players.  If a breeze developer wants to load these into a third party grid or serialize the objects using select() for a custom save it is much more difficult.  Creating a custom save serialization function is possible of course but to be honest I haven't gotten it working properly yet.  More homework for me.

Comment: We've been considering a method to "unwrap" any breeze entities. i.e. returning a collection of raw js objects.  It would not affect the EntityManager cache in any way.  If we had this, would it be useful for your use case?

Comment: Extremely useful.  I think a lot of developers are looking to get raw JSON back out of their object graphs for various but I have spent probably 3 days trying to do this to no avail.  The ko.toJS() works with some grids and such but say I am implementing a custom save and I want to pass JSON back to the server - all AJAX calls hiccup on entityType and entityAspect.  Deleting one or both properties throws an error in Breeze when it tries to update to a new value (when _$interceptor fires)  A Breeze default save doesn't have an option to maintain the structure (that I see at least)

Comment: To tack on to that, the custom serializer with Breeze only changes how the entities are serialized of course, not actually the structure that they are serialized in.

Comment: What if there were an `EntityManager.exportEntitiesToJson` that behaves like `EntityManager.exportEntities` but stops just short of  `JSON.stringify`? Combine this with breeze labs [`breeze.getEntityGraph`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.getEntityGraph.js) for selecting just the root entities and the related entities you want in an export. Would that fit the bill?

Comment: The JSON export feature has been added directly to `EntityManager.exportEntities`. When released (slated for v.1.5.3) you can review the [revised (extended) API for that method](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_exportEntities). This proposed change is in github now. It does NOT address the challenge of creating an entity graph w/o circularities although I think you now could make more progress toward that end.